# What are the implications of the EPR bridge information metric being invariant under all conditions, including distance in this universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

What if the reason why instantaneous state information is able be transmitted between entangled particles through an EPR bridge is that the metric that this is conveyed in is invariant under all conditions including displacement in the regular universe, and that's the reason it seems to travel faster than light? What are the implications of this?

Answer (score 1):

Invariance of the laws of physics under displacements doesn't imply entanglement, since classical theories that don't have entanglement are also invariant under displacement:

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9712154

All of the information you can access by measuring a quantum system is included in the expectation values of its observables. If you have two spatially separated entangled systems $S_1$ and $S_2$, the expectation values of measurements on $S_1$ are independent of anything that happens to $S_2$ and vice versa. So no information is transmitted faster than light.

If you compare measurement results on $S_1$ and $S_2$, then you will see results incompatible with a local theory in which $S_1$ and $S_2$ are described by stochastic variables and measurement devices' internal states aren't correlated with the measurements you will perform. Quantum mechanical equations of motion describe systems using Heisenberg picture observables,  which are Hermitian operators not stochastic variables. As such, Bell's theorem doesn't imply that quantum theory is non-local:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

Quantum equations of motion only allow observables of one system to depend on those of another as a result of interactions between them. In entanglement experiments those equations say that the correlations are established by locally inaccessible quantum information carried in decoherent systems.

Some modifications of quantum equations of motion that involve collapse

https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969

or classical particles that exist in addition to observables (e.g. - pilot wave theory)

https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.12175

may be non-local, but those theories are modifications of quantum theory and make different prediction. Also, they can't reproduce most of the predictions of quantum theory:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568

There is no instantaneous state transformation in quantum theory. There is no appearance of anything travelling faster than light in quantum theory. Since none of the premises of your question are true, those premises have no implications that are relevant in reality.